# Can a contributor in Azure use web deploy?

Tags: azure, webdeploy

I've been given a user in an Azure subscription that has the contributor role assigned to a specific resource group. I can create a web app without any issues inside that resource group, but I don't seem to be able to deploy to it using web deploy. I know I can create FTP credentials and deploy that way, but I would like to use web deploy. Is this possible? Or does it require administrator access to the Azure subscription in order to use web deploy?

Comment: Have you downloaded the publish profile?  The web deploy credentials and the FTP credentials are in that file.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?  Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: When I try to publish through VS once I select the correct account, it doesn't enable the drop down to select the site (and the server explorer displays a message about 'one or more of the subscriptions is not supported'). When I try to publish using PowerShell, I call the Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile, it launches a browser and I get a message saying that I have to be an administrator or co-administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I was just blind or if it was added after I asked the question (most likely the former, though I'd like to think it's the ladder), but when you are viewing the web app in the portal, one of the options in the toolbar (where the "Settings" and "Tools" are located), is "Get publish profile" (you may need to click "More commands" to see it).